# Куча ошибок при использовании npm с Angular

Tags: node.js, angular2, npm

Учу Angular на сайте [METANIT](https://metanit.com/web/angular2/1.1.php)

Все с точностью повторил все этапы, но все равно вываливается куча ошибок при использовании npm install, а также npm start.
P.S. Уже второй день находил кучу решений по этой проблеме, но ни одно не помогло.

```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~prestart: helloapp@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: helloapp@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\MyProjects\helloapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\mongodb\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin; C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Basenji\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\MyProjects\helloapp
11 silly lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" ' ]
12 silly lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle helloapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: helloapp@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid helloapp@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\MyProjects\helloapp
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.11.0
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error helloapp@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the helloapp@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the helloapp package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs helloapp
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls helloapp
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score -1):

У тебя проблема в том, что ты импортировал не тот EventEmitter.

Comment: А что нужно сделать, чтобы импортировать тот EventEmitter?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?